# How do I have a query tell me the total instances in a column AND the number of 'X' instances in a column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking at a public data set and I'd like to see what percent of loans are loanpurpose 1 and 2 vs not. I know I can solve this by hand using where loanpurpose = 1 or loanpurpose = 2. But If I do that, I don't get a count for the TOTAL number of loans a company does, I have to do that in a separate query and then combine data. So how do I get a count for loanpurpose 1,2 AND a total loancount all in the same query. Below is my attempt at doing to using expressions - BQ just ignores the <2 or =2. Italic means that part works, bold is the part in question:

```
SELECT
    activityyear,
    legalname,
    count(legalName) as UnitCountLegalName,
    sum(loanamount) as USDLoanVolume,
    count(loanPurpose < 2) as Purch,
    count(loanpurpose = 2) as Reno
FROM
    `xenon-broker-305718.HMDAplusLEI.QuoteLEICSVBothYrs`
where
    legalname = "Quicken Loans"
    and (actionTaken = 1 or actionTaken = 6)
group by
    legalname,
    activityYear
Limit  2
```

Thank you

EDIT: loanpurpose is an Integer

Comment: please povide sample dat and desired outpuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly , this is what you want to do:

```
SELECT
    activityyear,
    legalname,
    count(legalName) as UnitCountLegalName,
    sum(loanamount) as USDLoanVolume,
    count(case when loanPurpose < 2 then 1 else null end) as Purch,
    count(case when loanpurpose = 2 then 1 else null end) as Reno
FROM
    `xenon-broker-305718.HMDAplusLEI.QuoteLEICSVBothYrs`
where
    legalname = "Quicken Loans"
    and (actionTaken = 1 or actionTaken = 6)
group by
    legalname,
    activityYear
Limit  2
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Sounds like 'case' is almost like a subquery

Answer (score 0):

if everything is working
instead of

```
 count(loanPurpose < 2) as Purch,
    count(loanpurpose = 2) as Reno
```

try

```
sum (if (loanPurpose < 2 ,1,0)) as Purch,
    sum (if (loanpurpose = 2,1,0)) as Reno
```

Answer (score 0):

In BQ, you would express this as:

```
SELECT activityyear, legalname,
       count(*) as UnitCountLegalName,
       sum(loanamount) as USDLoanVolume,
       countif(loanPurpose < 2) as Purch,
       countif(loanpurpose = 2) as Reno
FROM  `xenon-broker-305718.HMDAplusLEI.QuoteLEICSVBothYrs`
where legalname = 'Quicken Loans' and
      actionTaken in (1, 6) and
      loanPurpose in (1, 2)
group by legalname, activityYear
Limit 2;
```

I added a filter on `loanpurpose` so it only considers values of 1 or 2.

The `count()` doesn't work because it counts non-NULL values.  The key is that you want `countif()`.

Comment: Count vs countif seems like the obvious correction. I tried your version and tried my version with just count->countif and for both: 'This query returned no results'

Comment: @Olivaw . . . This would only return no rows if there are no rows with `loanpurpose` = `1` or `2`.  Did I miss something in your question?  I thought these were the only types you wanted to count.

Comment: There are values for 1 and 2 but for some reason this phrasing doesn't execute correctly. For context, Eshirvana's answer above does run correctly

Comment: @Olivaw . . . Try removing that condition in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like:

```
SELECT activityyear, legalname, count(legalName) as UnitCountLegalName
, sum(loanamount) as USDLoanVolume
,sum(CASE when loanpurpose=1 then 1 else 0 end) as LP1Total
,sum(CASE when loanpurpose=2 then 1 else 0 end) as LP2Total
,count(*) as LPTotal
FROM xenon-broker-305718.HMDAplusLEI.QuoteLEICSVBothYrs 
where legalname = "Quicken Loans" and actionTaken in (1,6) and loanpurpose in (1,2)
group by legalname,activityYear Limit 2
```